# ContentDispatcherService: no listeners for an event TAB_STATE__GET_NAVIGATION_METHOD

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, websocket

I have tried to use many Map SDKs in React app but none of them have worked,
I have a list of errors whenever I try to render a map,
note that the API key has no restrictions and I suppose the problem is coming from React itself.

React V18

```
ContentDispatcherService: no listeners for an event TAB_STATE__GET_NAVIGATION_METHOD
```

````
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react_google_maps __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createClient) is not a function
    at MainPage.jsx:8:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26769:1
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _react_google_maps s__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createClient) is not a function
    at MainPage.jsx:8:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25154:1)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27351:1)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27330:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27056:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26769:1
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:1)
2react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <MainPage> component:

    at MainPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:910:63)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44956:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45422:5)
    at div
    at div
    at Feed
    at div
    at div
    at Home
    at div
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45360:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43562:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _tomtom_international_web_sdk_services__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createClient) is not a function
    at MainPage.jsx:8:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26769:1
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:1)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```
````

Comment: Recently i'm getting the same as log. @atadurdyyewserdar solution worked for me. Removed VPN and not getting such logs

Answer (score 3):

I also had this log. In my case I had VPN extension installed in Chrome. So deleted it and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing **React StrictMode**